# cucumber on windows - command not found

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm trying to get started with testing in Ruby on Windows, and I have the gems installed for cucumber

```
capybara (1.0.0, 0.4.1.1)
cucumber (0.10.2)
cucumber-rails (0.4.1)
rspec (2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.6.1)
webrat (0.7.3)
```

I wrote my first feature, but when I try to run

```
cucumber features -n
```

I get an error 'cucumber' is not a recognized internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How do you run cucumber tests under windows? I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.0

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue as you. The solution was to add the bin folder of the cucumber gem in the PATH environment variable:

`<path_to_jruby>\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\cucumber-1.2.1\bin`

This seams to be a windows related issue. Not sure why but it resolved the problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bundle exec cucumber features -n` should work.

Edit: Or maybe `rake cucumber`

Comment: 'bundle exec' returns 'bundler: command not found: cucumber' but I can see the gem when I run gem list. 'rake cucumber' tells me I have a nil object, but even running trace, it doesn't tell me where the nil object is, it just refers to rake lib files.

Comment: That's quite strange. I've always been using linux and mac so I don't really know what's going on for windows.

Answer (score 0):

There are few gotchas under windows like missing "a" character or no colored output but you should be able to use `cucumber` under windows just fine.

Try to setup cucumber again. Maybe you missed soemthing during setup. If that does not help, you could try to play with http://cygwin.com/index.html